# Alternative Input Device(Midi) doesn't prevent Screen Saver in Winforms application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, screensaver

I have developed a C# WinForms application whereby the user is providing input via a MIDI-connected device. The user will go for long periods without using the keyboard or mouse.

When I receive a MIDI message, is there anything I can do to "tell" the system that this counts as user activity (i.e., key press). I don't want the screen saver or time lockouts to occur if the MIDI device is actively being used.

I think my request is different than other requests I've seen because they want to disable screen savers for the life of their application whereby I just want MIDI input I receive to count as user interactivity.

Is there something I can call when I receive MIDI input to signify to the system user activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a CodeProject project that appears to do this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ScreenSaverControl.aspx

Looks like you can just call his `SetScreenSaverTimeout(GetScreenSaverTimeout())` method every time you receive MIDI input.

Comment: @sean e: the call appears to both set the idle time *and* reset the idle time timer to that amount (just *as if* the user moved the mouse or typed on the keyboard). In any case, not worthy of a down-vote, hmm?

Comment: If that's the case, then he should: SetScreenSaverTimeout(GetScreenSaverTimeout()).

Edit the answer and then I can change my vote.

Answer (score 1):

Windows sends out a message to each window before activating the screen saver or monitor power saver, all you need to do to prevent the screen from changing is to swallow these messages.

```
const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112, SC_SCREENSAVE = 0xF140, SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if( m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND ) //Intercept System Command
    {
        if( m.WParam.ToInt32() == SC_SCREENSAVE || m.WParam.ToInt32() == SC_MONITORPOWER )
        { 
            //Intercept ScreenSaver and Monitor Power Messages
            //MessageBox.Show("Reached SC/PowerCondition");
            return; // 
        }
    }   
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

The sample code, along with further reading, is from [this developer fusion thread.](http://www.developerfusion.com/forum/thread/49961/)

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144066%28VS.85%29.aspx : "Windows Vista and later: If password protection is enabled by policy, the screen saver is started regardless of what an application does with the SC_SCREENSAVE notification."